# S3 - get key of directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am working with Python Boto to work with S3. Let's say the name of the bucket is... bucket.

In bucket, I have a directory a. Within a, I have many other directories one, two, three... Within each of the directories one, two, three, etc., I have many files.

I am attempting to check if a directory such as a/x exists. I have tried something like this:

```
key = bucket.get_key('/a/one/')
```

but no luck. My workaround has been to return

```
list(bucket.list("a/", "/"))
```

and see if x exists in the list, but it seems messy. Also, within the returned list, i have 'a/' as a key. If 'a/', a directory, is a key, then shouldn't 'a/one/' also be one?

What is the best way of doing this? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

S3 does not have the concept of a directory. A directory is normally considered "existing" if there is a key with a path the same as the directory, but this example of a single key in a bucket is perfectly valid:

```
'/path/to/file/with/no/dir/file.txt'
```

Notice there are no key entries for:

```
'/path/'
'/path/to/'
```

Although there could be, but it has to be managed.

What you could do is see if any of the keys resides in the directory you're checking, something like:

```
dir_exists = any([k.startswith(path) for k in s3_file_names]),
```

Otherwise you have to maintain directory files in the bucket.

Comment: So, what I am doing right now with checking if x exists in the list isn't as messy as originally thought?

Comment: It may return a "False Negative" because there can be a file `/a/b/c` but no entry for directory `/a/b/`. What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe there is a better answer.

Comment: Simply, I want to check if a directory exists. In this case, I want to check of a/x where x is what I am checking, exists.

Comment: What if there is no entry for `/a/b/` but there is a key `/a/b/c` ? Would this mean there is no directory `/a/b`? because there is a key that is potentially mapped to a file in that directory.

Comment: Considering the directory structure I'm working with, if there is a a/b/c/, we can safe assume that there will always a/b/.

Comment: When you list the files, do you have the directory you're looking for as a key? if so, the results in your question are odd.